# Assigning variable to a type in a function, how can I have the type itself be an input that will describe the type of a variable output? : Swift 5

Tags: arrays, swift, swift5, typecasting-operator

I've made a file reading struct containing data, offsets and reading methods, (somehow fread() was confusing me).

I've gotten it working, and now want to implement a method into it that will take n x m matrix terms and output a matrix of values.  (Similar to fread(FileID, [ n m ], "(datatype)") in matlab).

Here is my idea

```
// should be able to handle all sorts of datatypes and output n by m matrix.
    mutating func matRead( dim : [[Int]], dtype : Int ){
        if dim.count != 2{
            fatalError("Dimensions dont match \"n by m\" in matRead")
        }
        // make sure to preallocate with zeros.
        
        var mat_Out : typecast[dtype][2].self = []
        
    }
```

I have a typecasting dictionary that looks so

```
// typecast dictionary key : [ array_type, byte, element_type ]
let typecast : [Int16:[Any]] = [ 1: [ [UInt8].self  , 1, "uint8"],
                              2: [ [UInt16].self , 2, "uint16"],  // use .self to reference data type itself.
                              3: [ [UInt32].self , 4, "uint32"],
                              4: [ [Int8].self   , 1, "int8"  ],
                              5: [ [Int16].self  , 2, "int16" ],
                              6: [ [Int32].self  , 4, "int32" ],
                              7: [ [Float32].self, 4, "float32"],
                              8: [ [Float64].self, 8, "float64"],
                              12:[ [Int32].self  , 4, "int32" ]   ]
```

Heres the question: line 8 of the matRead() function doesn't work.  Swift doesn't understand that I am trying to use the typecasting dictionary to assign to a new array type the output matrix. I've also tried "as"         `var mat_Out : Any = [] as typecast[dtype][0]`, also the same error (Swift compiler thinks I meant to put the brackets outside).

Alternatively I could go the long way and typecast manually based on the string values (already had to do this : see below fread struct code), but if there is another way it would be immensely time saving.

---

FileReading struct below ( redundant use of checking counts, but I haven't cleaned it up)

```
struct fRead {
    var off : Int = 0
    let data : Data
    
    mutating func resetOffsetToZero() {
        off = 0
    }
    
    mutating func setOffset( _ to : Int ) {
        off.self = to
    }
    mutating func moveOffset( _ by : Int) {
        off.self += by
    }
    func getOffset() -> Int {
        return off
    }
    // reading without specified number of elements defaults to 1.
    // these mutating funcs vary only in their output type and byte offset size.
    mutating func int32Read(count : Int = 1) -> [Int32] {
        var int32out : [Int32] = []
        if count > 1 {
            for i in 0...count-1 {
                int32out.append( Int32( data.subdata(in: off + i * 4..<(off + (i + 1) * 4) ).withUnsafeBytes{ $0.load(as: Int32.self )} ))
            }
            off += count * 4
        }
        else if count == 1 {
            int32out =  [ Int32( data.subdata(in: off..<(off+4) ).withUnsafeBytes{ $0.load(as: Int32.self )} )]
            off += 4
        }
        else if count == 0 {
            return []
        } else if count < 0{
            print("Warning, fReadint32Read( count : Int = 1) called with a negative count, returning empty array.")
        }
        return int32out
    }
    
    mutating func int16Read(count : Int = 1) -> [Int16] {
        var int16out : [Int16] = []
        if count > 1 {
            for i in 0...count-1 {
                int16out.append( data.subdata(in: off + i * 2..<(off + (i + 1) * 2) ).withUnsafeBytes{ $0.load(as: Int16.self )} )
            }
            off += count * 2
        }
        else if count == 1 {
            int16out =  [ data.subdata(in: off..<(off+2) ).withUnsafeBytes{ $0.load(as: Int16.self )} ]
            off += 2
        }
        else if count == 0 {
            return []
        } else if count < 0 {
            print("Warning, fRead.int16Read( count : Int = 1) called with a negative count, returning empty array.")
        }
        return int16out
    }
    
    mutating func float64Read(count : Int = 1) -> [Float64] {
        var float64out : [Float64] = []
        if count > 1 {
            for i in 0...count-1 {
                float64out.append( data.subdata(in: off + i * 8..<(off + (i + 1) * 8) ).withUnsafeBytes{ $0.load(as: Float64.self )} )
            }
            off += count * 8
        }
        else if count == 1 {
            float64out =  [ data.subdata(in: off..<(off+8) ).withUnsafeBytes{ $0.load(as: Float64.self )} ]
            off += 8
        }
        else if count == 0 {
            return []
        } else if count < 0 {
            print("Warning, fRead.int16Read( count : Int = 1) called with a negative count, returning empty array.")
        }
        return float64out
    }
    
    mutating func uint32Read(count : Int = 1) -> [UInt32] {
        var uint32out : [UInt32] = []
        if count > 1 {
            for i in 0...count-1 {
                uint32out.append( data.subdata(in: off + i * 4..<(off + (i + 1) * 4) ).withUnsafeBytes{ $0.load(as: UInt32.self )} )
            }
            off += count * 4
        }
        else if count == 1 {
            uint32out =  [ data.subdata(in: off..<(off+4) ).withUnsafeBytes{ $0.load(as: UInt32.self )} ]
            off += 4
        }
        else if count == 0 {
            return []
        } else if count < 0 {
            print("Warning, fRead.int16Read( count : Int = 1) called with a negative count, returning empty array.")
        }
        return uint32out
    }
    
    mutating func int64Read(count : Int = 1) -> [Int64] {
        var int64out : [Int64] = []
        if count > 1 {
            for i in 0...count-1 {
                int64out.append( Int64( data.subdata(in: off + i * 4..<(off + (i + 1) * 8) ).withUnsafeBytes{ $0.load(as: Int64.self )} ))
            }
            off += count * 8
        }
        else if count == 1 {
            int64out =  [ Int64( data.subdata(in: off..<(off+8) ).withUnsafeBytes{ $0.load(as: Int64.self )} )]
            off += 8
        }
        else if count == 0 {
            return []
        } else if count < 0{
            print("Warning, fReadint64Read( count : Int = 1) called with a negative count, returning empty array.")
        }
        return int64out
    }
    // should be able to handle all sorts of datatypes and output n by m matrix.
    mutating func matRead( dim : [[Int]], dtype : Int ){
        if dim.count != 2{
            fatalError("Dimensions dont match \"n by m\" in matRead")
        }
        // make sure to preallocate with zeros.
        
        var mat_Out : Any = [] as typecast[dtype][0]
        
    }
}

// I only discovered afterwards that 0...0 range works! So all the testing for  ==1 , == 0 wasn't necessary
```

Comment: Are you trying to refactor all the `xxxRead` methods into one single method?

Comment: This is not necessary because in my main program I've organized all the different readings.      It would have been cleaner by merging into one method, but I've managed without doing this.  I'm trying not to do the same thing when making my matrix reader.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wouldn't a generic solution be the best way forward here? Below is a generic version when the elements are integer so a similar function is needed for floats (`BinaryFloatingPoint`).

```
mutating func matRead<T: BinaryInteger>(count: Int = 1) -> [T] {
    var intOut : [T] = []
    let width = T().bitWidth / 8
    if count > 1 {
        for i in 0...count-1 {
            intOut.append( T( data.subdata(in: off + i * 4..<(off + (i + 1) * width) ).withUnsafeBytes{ $0.load(as: T.self )} ))
        }
        off += count * width
    }
    else if count == 1 {
        intOut =  [ T( data.subdata(in: off..<(off+width) ).withUnsafeBytes{ $0.load(as: T.self )} )]
        off += width
    }
    else if count == 0 {
        return []
    } else if count < 0{
        print("Warning, fReadint64Read( count : Int = 1) called with a negative count, returning empty array.")
    }
    return intOut
}
```

Note that there is a "bug" in the code above, I wasn't sure what to replace 4 with in `i * 4..<(off + (i + 1)` since you have used that number so inconsistently between your functions. I guess it should be `width / 2` but I leave it to you to update that part.

Comment: This did end up being close to what I ended up doing.  I'm trying this form of the functions : (there will be two)

Comment: Great idea I'm trying to conform the function like your answer one for Binary(Integer/FloatingPiont)
`mutating func fromfileBI<T : BinaryInteger>(count : Int = 1) -> [T]? { 
        let byteSize = MemoryLayout<T>.stride
        var swiftTypeOut : [T] = []        
        if count > 1 {
            swiftTypeOut = [T].init(repeating: 0, count: count)
            for i in 0...count-1 {
                swiftTypeOut[i] = data.subdata(in: off + i * byteSize..<off + (i + 1) * byteSize ).withUnsafeBytes{ $0.load(as: T.self )}
            }
            off += count * byteSize
        }
   }`